# with open(fn, 'rb') as f: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/widgy/page_builder/html.scss'

Tags: django

I encounter, at all times, when i try to bind, scss and widgy, the same error. 
    With any django version, since 1.6.8 to 1.7.3,the last release, and django_pyscss any version, and finally django-widgy to 0.3.3 or other, always the same issue.

```
There my stack trace on PyDev :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\workspace\MezzaTest2\manage.py", line 32, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\olive\Environnements\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\olive\Environnements\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\olive\Environnements\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\olive\Environnements\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Users\olive\Environnements\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\olive\Environnements\lib\site-packages\widgy\contrib\page_builder\models.py", line 16, in <module>
    from widgy.contrib.page_builder.db.fields import MarkdownField, VideoField, ImageField
  File "C:\Users\olive\Environnements\lib\site-packages\widgy\contrib\page_builder\db\fields.py", line 13, in <module>
    from widgy.contrib.page_builder.forms import MarkdownField as MarkdownFormField, MarkdownWidget
  File "C:\Users\olive\Environnements\lib\site-packages\widgy\contrib\page_builder\forms\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    class CKEditorWidget(forms.Textarea):
  File "C:\Users\olive\Environnements\lib\site-packages\widgy\contrib\page_builder\forms\__init__.py", line 80, in CKEditorWidget
    'contentsCss': scss_compile('/widgy/page_builder/html.scss'),
  File "C:\Users\olive\Environnements\lib\site-packages\widgy\contrib\page_builder\forms\__init__.py", line 22, in scss_compile
    css_content = scss.compile(scss_file=scss_filename)
  File "C:\Users\olive\Environnements\lib\site-packages\pyscss-1.3.0.a1-py2.7.egg\scss\legacy.py", line 163, in compile
    is_sass=is_sass,
  File "C:\Users\olive\Environnements\lib\site-packages\pyscss-1.3.0.a1-py2.7.egg\scss\source.py", line 100, in from_filename
    with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/widgy/page_builder/html.scss'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are running the 1.3.0a1 version of PyScss. Widgy depends on django-pyscss, which currently only supports the 1.2.1 version of PyScss currently. I know that you tried a lot of different versions, but did you try to install `PyScss==1.2.1`?

Comment: Hi, in fact, There  haven't got PyScss==1.2.1. The last release is the 2.0.1. The error ( with the last release ) is that from django_pyscss.scss import DjangoScss, is not recognized. Erf, I turnaround.

Comment: with a python 2.7, in fact i haven't got any problem with pyscss, but anyway, the display of the components, callouts, page builder, etc, are incomplete.

Comment: Hi, PyScss and django-pyscss are actually two different projects. In PyScss 1.3, they broke compatibility with the old API, so django-pyscss had to update in 2.0.  Unfortunately, widgy doesn't support django-pyscss 2.0 just quite yet. We just need to release it (should be tomorrow) and then all the problems that you've been having should get cleared up.